# Xamarin.Forms and .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm starting a new Xamarin.Forms project for my own App, I've to use this Plugin: [Bluetoothle](https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle) that's compatible only with **.NET Standard 2.0**, I already setting up my project and everything works fine.

My question is: it is advisable to use .NET Standard 2.0 with Xamarin.Forms now?

My fear is to have an incompatibility during the development process of my app. For example, I've tried to install **Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps** and a Warning compared:

> Package 'Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps 2.3.0' was restored using
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.

So I want to ask you is anybody already using .NET Standard 2.0 with Xamarin and if you have some kind of problem with it.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can use .NET Standard with Xamarin.Forms quite safely. Most packages which display the warning you mentioned have previously targeted a Portable Class Library, which definitely had lower API surface than .NET Standard.

In most cases everything will work as expected as long as the library doesn't call some API that is unavailable or not implemented in .NET Standard. This however happens mostly just for some libraries that previously targeted the full .NET Framework are using some Windows-specific APIs.

The best advice then would be to test the app and all "corner" cases as much as possible, but you should be safe when using well supported PCL libraries.

Comment: Thanks, I will try my most used PCL Libraries to know if everything works fine.

Comment: Do note that [.NET Standard is the replacement for PCLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#comparison-to-portable-class-libraries). If the PCLs are directly under your control, you should seriously consider upgrading them to .NET Standard, which will decrease the chance of these incompatibilities.